# Accessing SQL array element from Libreoffice Basic with Postgres DB

Tags: arrays, postgresql, stored-procedures, libreoffice, basic

This is a followup with the discussion at:

[Accessing SQL array element from Libreoffice Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310745/accessing-sql-array-element-from-libreoffice-basic)

I have almost the same problem. I am following the above mentioned code, but I get an error. Here is what I have done:

1. The table is:

```
CREATE TABLE temp.table2
(
  names character varying[],
  names2 text[]
);
insert into temp.table2(names, names2) values (ARRAY['a','b','c','d','e'], ARRAY['a','b','c','d','e']);

insert into temp.table2(names, names2) values (ARRAY['1','2','3','4','5'], ARRAY['1','2','3','4','5']);

insert into temp.table2(names, names2) values (ARRAY['e','d','c','b','a'], ARRAY['e','d','c','b','a']);
```

2. The LO Basic:

```
Sub Main
    If isnull(ThisDatabaseDocument.currentcontroller.activeconnection) Then
        ThisDatabaseDocument.currentcontroller.connect("root", "root")
    End if
    pgCon=ThisDatabaseDocument.currentcontroller.activeconnection
    stmt = pgCon.createStatement()
    
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("select names,names2 from temp.table2")
    rs2 = rs.getMetadata()
    While rs.Next
        dar = rs.getString(1).getArray(Null)
    Wend 
End Sub
```

on the line

```
dar = rs.getString(1).getArray(Null)
```

The error appears:

```
BASIC runtime error.
Object variable not set.
```

So seemingly I am doing everything correct; however, I get an error.

This however, is not my goal. I would like to use XArray in the following manner:

1. Here is my pgSQL code:

```
    create or replace function temp.f_iu7YttW(dname text[]) returns void as $$
    declare
    counter integer = 1;
    begin
        while counter<=50 loop
            insert into temp.table1(name) values(dname[counter]);
            counter=counter+1;
        end loop;
    end; $$ language plpgsql;
```

2. Here is my Basic code:

```
Sub Main
Dim stmt As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim sql As String
Dim a As Variant
Dim x As Long
    If isnull(ThisDatabaseDocument.currentcontroller.activeconnection) Then
        ThisDatabaseDocument.currentcontroller.connect("root", "root")
    End if
    pgCon=ThisDatabaseDocument.currentcontroller.activeconnection
    executeDDLPg("drop function if exists temp.f_iu7YttW(text[])")
    myDict= getScriptForgeDictionary()
    x=0
    a= Array(x & "")
    SF_Array.Append(a)
    For x = 1 To 50
        a=SF_Array.Append(a,x & "")
    Next x
    max = ubound(a)
    sql ="drop function if exists temp.f_iu7YttW(text[]);" & _
    "create or replace function temp.f_iu7YttW(dname text[]) returns void as $$ " & _
    "declare "  & _
    "counter integer = 1; "  & _
    "begin "  & _
    "   while counter<" & max & " loop "  & _
    "       insert into temp.table1(name) values(dname[counter]); "  & _
    "       counter=counter+1; "  & _
    "   end loop; "  & _
    "end; $$ language plpgsql;" ' & _
    executeDDLPg(sql)
    sql="select temp.f_iu7YttW(?);\n" ' & _
    stmt = pgCon.prepareStatement(sql)
    
    stmt.setString(1,a)
    stmt.executeUpdate()
    stmt.clearParameters()
    closeDbObject(stmt)
    executeDDLPg("drop function temp.f_iu7YttW(text[])")
End Sub
```

This code does not work. If I replace `stmt.setString(1,a)` with `stmt.setArray(1,a)` then LO crashes.

Comment: I have a partial solution to the first part of my problem. Here is the code:```
  dar = rs.getArray(1)(0).getArray(Null)
```
gets the value of the array as a variant.

Comment: This is very strange. If someone can please explain does not make any difference if I use ***dar = rs.getArray(1)(0).getArray(Null)*** or ***dar = rs.getArray(-99)(0).getArray(Null)*** or even ***dar = rs.getArray(135)(0).getArray(Null)***. Does anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: I haven't read carefully through the entire question yet, but shouldn't it be something like this: `dar = rs.getArray(1); dbasicarr = dar.getArray(Null)`. The `1` is for `names` instead of `names2`, while I don't see why the second index would be needed. Then get a specific value with for example `dstring = dbasicarr(2)`. Until you have a clear solution, it might help to break up the `getArray` statements into two separate lines to make it easier to see what is happening.

Comment: One more idea: perhaps a `RowSet` would help as described at https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-to-make-a-resultset-read-write/54280/2. Ratslinger from that site is an expert on these topics, so if you post a question there then maybe he will see it.

Comment: Thank you for your input. This problem has resulted in a bug report. Here are the details: [link](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=154464)

Comment: The follow-up question is at https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/looping-through-an-array-in-an-stored-function-in-postgres/89806.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bug in LO. A bug report was posted and here is the link:

https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=154464